# Macro works with one sheet but not on multiple

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a macro that will search though a list and find all the entries in a column that has "spectraseven" at the first. This will be to copy these records to a sheet for each entry.

This macro works when there is only one sheet in the workbook but when there are more it gives me the error `object or variable with block not set` on the line with the arrow at the end. (`If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then`)

```
Function mySheetData(SheetName As String) As Boolean

'
'By Joe Was
    'This adds a sheet and names it "Test."
    'SheetName = Sheets(1).Range("a1")
    Sheets.Add.Name = SheetName

    'This selects your new sheet and moves it after sheet "Sheet3," which could be any sheet name.
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Sheets(SheetName).Move After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)

    'this selects the sheet with the data and its range.
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A1:c20").Select

    'This will copy and paste the data to your new sheet "Test."
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'At this point your data will be on the new sheet and selected for the next step.

End Function
'copy from template sheet
'add information from each summary sheet to the tech sheets

'Function MoveToTables(manName As String, startCell As Integer, cellRange As String) As Boolean
Sub testWild()
startCell = 1
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr As String
Dim technum As String

cellRange = "e1:e500"
topCount = startCell
With Range("e1:e500")
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
Dim findString As String
findString = "SPECTRASEVEN*"
Set FoundCell = Sheets(1).Range(cellRange).Find(what:=findString, After:=LastCell)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
End If
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
    Count = FoundCell.Row
    technum = Right(FoundCell, 4)
    Set FoundCell = Range(cellRange).FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    temp = mySheetData(technum)
    ' vv This is the line with the error vv
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
             Exit Do
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not checking to  see if a cell was found before using `FoundCell.Address`. If the first call to `FindCell` (after initializing `foundString` doesn't find a match, you're using it in the loop anyway (`Do Until` when `FoundCell` could be nothing at the start). Also, if `FindNext` doesn't find another cell (you're already on the last one), what would you expect `FoundCell` to be referencing?

Comment: I dont quite understand all that you have said but `FoundCell` has the value of the cell that it has found. It can't get to the if statment until it has checked if `FoundCell` is found. The real strange thing is that it works just fine with one sheet and sometimes it will run though the loop once before it throws the error.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code. You're not finding anything with `FindNext`, but you're accessing `FoundCell.Address` even if it fails at least once before you loop around to check the `Do Until` condition is tested again.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are advancing to the next cell before the test for `Nothing` has a chance to occur.

This example is for printing single digit numbers:

```
Sub test1()

Dim j

j = 1
Do Until j = 10
    Debug.Print j
    j = j + 1
    If j = 10 Then Debug.Print "oops, why no exit?"
    Debug.Print j
Loop

End Sub
```

if you run this code, you will see the message that gets printed when j=10, even though it looks like the loop should end.
Fixing the increment to occur right at the end of the loop, so the test can work, gives this:

```
Sub test2()

Dim j

j = 1

j = j + 1
Do Until j = 10
    Debug.Print j
    If j = 10 Then Debug.Print "oops, why no exit?"
    Debug.Print j
    j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

note that I now have 2 increments, one before the loop begins (just in case j happens to be 9 before I start my testing) and one at the end, so the loop can test at the right point